# Map not showing up using Leaflet in JSP page.Tiles are available

Tags: javascript, jsp, dictionary, offline, leaflet

We are trying to show offline maps in Web application. Succeeded in extracting the required portion and converting them into tiles.

The **tiles** folder is located inside the **WEB-INF** and all the required folder for tiles is present inside the tiles folder.

**Leaflet** script is present inside the **script** folder.
**css** script is present inside the **css** folder.

The code snippet of my page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demon</title>
<link href="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/css/general.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/css/leaflet.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script src="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/script/leaflet.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext['request'].contextPath}/script/leaflet-src.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script>
function Demo()
{

    var map = L.map('map');
    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<div id="map" style="width:800px;height:600px;">
<a4j:commandButton value="HIT" onclick="Demo()"></a4j:commandButton>
</div>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Now on my page, when I click on **HIT** button , the map portion is taken up and displayed in the browser in the space allocated but NOTHING IN THE MAPS SHOW..

**Powered by Leaflet and Zoom in/out icon definitely comes.**

**NO MAP IS SHOWN.** The tile images which are present in the folder do contain a map which was extracted and converted into the tiles.

Hence I am unable to figure out why nothing is appearing at all. Please guide me.

I think i am very close to showing a map and nonetheless it has been one hell of a ride to explore this and arrive till this point.

Comment: I'm not saying taht you won't get an answer just as quickly (if not quicker) here, but have you considered asking this over at [gis.stckexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com). Its where all the map nerds (like me!) hang out. Just a thought for the future?

Comment: Well I can think of asking there.But do you know what I am doing wrong over here..Why the map is not being displayed

Comment: I'm an OpenLayers man and not a Leaflet man I am afraid. Apologies if I am telling you something you already know but have you checked it in Firebug and seen if the tiles are being requested at all, or if it is throwing some other script errors?

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing using OpenLayers API. I mean which one is easier to use. Leaflet or OpenLayers. I am starting off so I can afford to switch provided it helps my cause.

Comment: IMHO, there are some mistakes here:<br/>

- putting the commandButton into the map-div

- including leaflet.js AND leaflet-src.js

Comment: IMHO, there are some mistakes here:
putting the commandButton into the map-div, including leaflet.js AND leaflet-src.js. And the prefix thing is unneccessary (${pageContext['request'].contextPath}), since the addresses are local anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did this it may help, I used \ as an escape character before `$` so JSP can understand the url containg `${}`, or it will consider it an empty variable?

Problem:

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Damascus", "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, alpha: true, isBaseLayer: true});
```

Solution:

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Damascus", "tiles/\${z}/\${x}/\${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, alpha: true, isBaseLayer: true});
```